# How to proof minimum path length for a grid will always be width + height?

Tags: graph-theory

Imagine a square grid where each node is connected to the node above and the node to its right.

So for a 2 x 2 grid the structure would be -:

```
10 11
00 01
```

00 is connected to 01 and 10. While 01 is connected to 11 and 10 is connected to 11.

If I keep the constraint that starting from a point I can only move either up or right, if I have to get from 00 to 11 all my distinct paths are always `width + height` distance long assuming  the movement from one cell to the other is 1 unit of distance. How would I prove this ?

*My attempts to proof this is as follows-:*

Since we are always making a positive step to the end result therefore I can never end up with a path that is longer than `width + height` units of distance. For example from 10 we cannot move down, we can only move left.

But how do I construct a formal proof out of this ?

1. How would I proof that `width + height` distance is the minimum
   distance achievable when trying to get from `(00)` to `(nn)` ?
2. And how do I proof that traversing in the above fashion generates all paths
   that are `width + height` long ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a *less* formal proof to get you started:
Let '$R$' be a move $1$ step *right*, and '$U$' be a move $1$ step *up*. Then to get to the point $(p,q)$, we must have $p$ $R$s and $q$ $U$s in some order.

For example, for a grid that has width $2$ and height $3$, then one possible combination would be $RRUUU$. However, if we add one more $R$ or $U$ to this sequence, then no matter where you place it, the sequence after that will be one step right or up. Since the original path takes us to $(2,3)$, but we shifted it by adding an extra move, we will never get back to $(2,3)$ this way.

In fact, all possible possibilities of moves are combinations of the same sequence – such as $RRUUU$ in our example. There are $p+q$ moves in total, and we have to rearrange the $p$ $R$ moves. This gives us $p+q \choose p$ sequences possible.

Answer (score 1):

Proof sketch using induction / contradiction: Look at the smallest grid (with some reasonable notion of "smallest") where this is *not* true. Note that after taking one step, you are basically starting over in a smaller grid, with `width + height` one less.